# "Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors *" from android_asset

Tags: android, webview, content-security-policy

I am writing an Android-App, which loads a local webpage, and that page, posts to some inner iframe, which in reply will display data regarding that user.

The remote site refuses to display on my `android_asset/page.html` because of:

`Refused to display 'https://example/foo/bar' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors *".`

My code is:

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    // this should do the trick... but it does not
    Map<String, String> extra  = new HashMap<>();
    extra.put("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors *" );
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page.html", extra);
```

BTW: Doing this, will not help as its not supported:

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-ancestors *">
 </head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was simple:

I changed from `loadUrl()` to `loadDataWithBaseUrl()`, code:

```
    try {
        String thePage = readRawText(getAssets().open("page.html"));
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://my-epic-site/", thePage, "text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

```
public static String readRawText(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    if (inputStream == null) {
        return null;
    }

    BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
    String currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
    while (currentLine != null) {
        fileContent.append(currentLine);
        fileContent.append("\n");
        currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
    return fileContent.toString();
}
```

This makes the page, thinks it originated from the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for this workaround. Here is simplified readRawText() implementation.

```
    public String readRawText(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[input.available()];
        input.read(buf);
        input.close();
        return new String(buf);
    }
```